# Shell Bash Add extension to files without one

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am trying to create a scrits that can find files without an extension and add "html" to the end of it. I was able to create a small script to get anything without a "." in the end, however sometimes people have file with "." in it's name without being related to it's extension and i don't known what to do about that.

Here's is an example:

```
File1.xml
File2.txt
File3
File.4
File5.sh
File6
```

This is what i have so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd TestFiles
dir=$(pwd)

echo "Searching Files Without Extension"


array=$(find . -type f ! -name "*.*")

echo $array

for file in $array; do
    filename=$(basename "$file");
    echo $filename
    #extension=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'.' -f2)
    mv -f $filename $filename".html"

done

ls
```

Again, the code above works but only if the file does not have a "." on it's name.

Comment: Your "array" isn't an array at all -- it's just a string, and if you had a file with spaces in its name, it would be broken into multiple iterations by the loop.

Comment: To *actually* read results from `find` into an array looks more like this: `array=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do array+=( "$file" ); done < <(find . -type f ! -name '*.*' -print0)` -- and then, to iterate through it: `for file in "${array[@]}"; do ...` -- though there's no particular reason to use the array at all, in that case, as opposed to just putting your logic right inside the `while read` loop.

Comment: Anyhow, in `File.4`, `4` **is** an extension. I don't know what you mean by "without being related to its extension" -- a file's extension *is* the string after the last `.` in the name. If you want to write a filter that ignores extensions with non-alpha characters, or extensions longer than four characters, or whatever, you could do that... but there's no convention about what is and isn't an extension, so you'd need to actually come up with a decision on what rules you want to enforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and compatible with all POSIX-compliant shells:

```
for f in *; do
  case $f in *.*) continue;; esac
  mv -- "$f" "${f}.html"
done
```

Comment: Can explain to me ho this code works exactly? I am kinda new to shell.

Comment: See [the case statement](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case), and [globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) on the bash-hackers' wiki, and [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) entry #10 re: `--`. If you have open questions after reading those links, please ask them explicitly.